# How can i connect my phone camera to my pc

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create an app like droidcam for my diploma and i have no idea from where to start or how to achieve it.I was wondering if there is any guide or any place i can learn from.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you have some ideas about how the program should work like but are not sure about the implementation, Github is always a good place to do some research and learn from other people's code :-)

You can check this project:

https://github.com/imakhilc/DroidCamera